# How to call an overloaded command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, zip, pscx

My PowerShell environment has two `Expand-Archive` commands:

- Windows 10 -> a function from Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive (1.0.1.0)
- PowerShell Community Extension -> a CmdLet from Pscx (3.2.2)

My current environment defaults to the CmdLet from Pscx:

```
PS> (Get-Command Expand-Archive).ModuleName
Pscx
```

Is there any syntax (fully qualified name) to call a command from another module?
I do not want to unload Pscx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always call a function with its fully-qualified module name.

In your example:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Expand-Archive -Path $Path -Destination $Dest
```

I *think* when you don't specify the module, it uses whatever was loaded last

Comment: You could even alias that to something less cumbersome.

Comment: @EBGreen: You can, but then you're introducing another point of failure.  If I suspect I have a polluted environment, I'd full-path everything in a script (since it's only being written once).  Fun-fact: I've had some servers with no environment variables and altered built-in modules.

Comment: I would full path everything in a script too. I was thinking of working at the prompt which is where I spend a lot of my time.

Comment: @EBGreen that makes sense.  I spend most of my time automating deployments/configs and writing scripts